# I want to display a random object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display a random object in cards.

```html
<div class="row">
  <% @slots.sample(3).each do |slot| %>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card-image">
      <%= link_to slot_path(slot) do %>
        <% if slot.photo? %>
          <%= cl_image_tag slot.photo, class: "img-rounded img-responsive", height: 262, width: 195 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "image_placeholder.jpg", class: "fileinput-new thumbnail img-no-padding", height: 250, width: 400 %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="details">
          <div class="author">
          <%= link_to slot_user(slot) do %>
            <%= cl_image_tag slot.user.photo, class: "img-circle img-no-padding img-responsive" %>
            <span class="name"><%= slot.name %></span>
            <span class="meta"><%= slot.user.first_name %> <%= slot.user.last_name %></span>
          <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

My code returns error messages like:

```
"undefined method `sample' for nil:NilClass",
"undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass",
"undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass"
```

I don't understand. Can you help me?

Comment: thanks sawa for your correction ! it's a first time that i post to stackoverflow =)

Comment: What is `@slots`? How does a `slot` look like?

Comment: @slots is undefined (nil)... you never set it up.

Comment: i just checked in my controller, `@slot` was'nt defined... In my controller, my home method content now : `@slots = Slots.all`

But i think that is not enough...

the new error message is : `uninitialized constant PagesController::Slots`

Comment: aaaaargh ! my problem was is my controller ! it's corrected !!! Thanks to you, I was able to go back to the source of the problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize your @slots collection in the conntroller, eg:

```
@slots = Slot.where(id: Slot.pluck(:id).sample(3))
```

Then use directly in the view

```
<% @slots.each do |slot| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a random object in Ruby on Rails (ActiveRecord) is not well documented but it is fairly easy.

There is the obvious: take two random objects from any array:

```
@users = User.all
@users.sample(2)
```

This will get all objects from the db, put them in an array (@users) from which two random objects are picked. If you happen to need all objects in an array this is fine. If not, you better go for something better:

```
User.order('RANDOM()').limit(2)
```

This will only read two entries from the db, using a random order. It is therefore much easier on the db than the first command.

The command syntax works for PostgreSQL - use 'RAND()' for MySQL.

There is one thing to watch out for and that is a default_scope. If you have set a default_scope for the obj class use reorder instead:

```
User.reorder('RANDOM()').limit(2)
```